# combine xgb feature importance

Tags: r, xgboost, feature-importances

Is it possible to combine the results from the xgb.boost importance function. For example, due to one hot encoding, I have a feature age=35 and another age=60. Is there a way that I can add these to get an overall importance of age, and not just age at every value? In case it matters the model is a binary:logistic one.

```
library(xgboost)
imp_matrix= xgb.importance(features,model=mod)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just sum them.

The three importances reported are all fractions that a given feature contributes out of the total.  The measures are Gain, the impurity improvement a split provides; Cover, the number of datapoints passing through a node; and Frequency, just the number of nodes.  All of these are summed across the nodes that use a given feature to split, and so adding them together across dummy variables for a given categorical also makes sense.